# How to release events?

Tags: opencl

Suppose I have a kernel that must wait for 5 events to complete before running. How do I safely release these 5 events once the kernel has started ?

One way would be to fire a callback when the kernel completes, and release the events at that time, but this seems awkward.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can safely release the events as soon as you have enqueued the kernel that waits on them. The OpenCL specification's description of `clReleaseEvent` includes this paragraph:

> The event object is deleted once the reference count becomes zero, the specific command identified by this event has completed (or terminated) **and there are no commands in the command-queues of a context that require a wait for this event to complete**.

The `clReleaseEvent` function just decrements the reference count, but won't actually destroy the event if there are other references to it from commands that are executing or pending execution.

Comment: Thanks. I am still unclear about the flow:  1. create an event (ref count set to 1).  2. set kernel to wait on event (ref count set to 2)    3. clReleaseEvent  (ref count set to 1).  So, when will this event be cleaned up (ref count set to zero) ?

Comment: Does the ref count get decremented when the kernel that is waiting on it gets triggered ?

Comment: The API will essentially perform an implicit retain when you enqueue the command, and then release when the command is complete. So in your example, the event would be destroyed when the kernel finishes execution.

Comment: Further to that, there's no guarantee about what the ref count is. Think of your creation/retain/release pattern as influencing only the host side of the ref count. User ref count starts at 1, ends at 0. There may be added to that a device ref count, or there may be a separate device ref count. Either way the device will hold references to things it is using. The point of all this is to say: don't rely on the value of the ref count for anything.

Comment: Thanks, Lee. I don't check the ref count. I just follow the rule of calling release to match each time I create an event.

Comment: In my case I just needed to explicitly release events that I passed into `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel`, since without, the memory wasn't released automatically.